# Unable to connect to an upgraded EC2 windows instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

I have a t2.medium instance running windows server 2008 and I want to change it to a m5.large instance. When I stop it and change it to m5.large instance when I try to connect to it via RDP it throws an error saying that maybe my machine isn't running. If I change it again to a t2.medium instance, I am able again to connect to it via RDP.

Do you have any solution to fix this? Or is it a bug?

Thanks you all

Comment: The public IP address changes when you stop and then start an instance. Maybe edit the RDP connection details.

Comment: That wasn't the problem, it has a static IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M5 instance type uses the new hypervisor from AWS called [Nitro](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#ec2-hypervisor). If the AMI you originally launched isnt compatible with Nitro it could cause issues. Try switching to an M4.Large or something other then a M5 or C5 and see if the issue persists.